# How to read excel file on a Java-Web Start Application

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am developing a java-web-start application that reads excel files using java POI. My problem is whenever I run my code it returns an error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory
    at digicare.tracking.serial.BulkUpload.UploadProgress$1read2.run(UploadProgress.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Here's my code:

```
try {
            InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int maxrows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        for (int r = 1; r < maxrows; r++) { 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            lblCurrentRow.setText(String.valueOf(r));
            prbProgBar.setValue(r);                                       
                    txtOutPut.append(String.format("Done!!\n"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this before, actually there is not only one jar file to add, there is another one, named : poi-ooxml-x.jar (where x is the version) , it's this file that contains WorkbookFactory, not the poi-x.jar, you have to include both of them

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT**
I did some research and i think your classpath problem is related to your project being a java web start application :

> Can I rely on Class-Path in the Manifest file?
>
> Java Web Start does not support the Class-Path entry in the manifest
>   file. The Class-Path attribute is entirely file-centric, where as Java
>   Web Start and JNLP is Web-centric, i.e., based on URLs. Thus, the two
>   models do not merge easily.
>
> Instead of relying on the Class-Path entry, you can list multiple JAR
>   files in the JNLP file, e.g.,:
>
> ```
> <resources>
>      <jar href="A.jar"/> 
>      <jar href="B.jar"/>  
> </resources>
> ```

here is the link where i found it : http://webstartfaq.com/#52

Comment: i got the poi-ooxml-3.9

Comment: YOU NAILED IT!! I simply called my jar files in my jnlp and then it worked like magic!! Thank you very much! hahaha after a week of nonesense this finally solves my problem! :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it cant find the WorkbookFactory. Assuming you have put Apache POI jar in the build path. Can you see if org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory class is there in the jar file it self?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some of the POI jars. Specifically, you are certainly missing the `poi-ooxml` jar, but you may be missing some others too...

Apache POI provide [a handy page listing components, their jars and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components). As that page explains, if you want to use the common `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` classes (eg [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html)) you need the main POI jar, the POI-OOXML jar, and their respective dependencies.

If you add those two jars and [their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), and/or switch to maven and list your project as depending on `poi` plus `poi-ooxml` you'll have the classes you need

Comment: I got all the poi jar file like the poi-ooxml-3.9

Comment: The jars, and their dependencies, need to be present to both compile *and* run. Having them there at just compile time isn't enough, they need to also be in place on your classpath when the code runs. Based on the exception you don't

Comment: I do have all the jar files on my class path.

Comment: Clearly you don't, otherwise they'd be found! Java Web Start is a bit fussy about jars and classpaths, you might need to double check you've done the right thing for it to be happy with them

Comment: I have but the thing is I put it inside the main jar file? is that ok?